# Centos 6.5, WHM : Rsync with Root disabled using ssh user from the Wheel Group

Tags: ssh, cpanel, rsync, whm

I'm trying to rsync files with my server, which has root login via ssh disabled. I'm trying to use one of the users I've created and added to to the wheel group. Usually - when I log in via ssh I run

```
su - root
```

then type the password and can run everything as `root` user, but not quite sure how to do it with `rsync` as I need to upload the files outside of the user directory.

When I run:

```
rsync -avz files/* sshwheeluser@ip_address:/home/newproject/public_html/
```

I get:

```
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/home/newproject/public_html/": Permission denied (13)
```

I have added the following to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
rsyncuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

plus I've un-commented:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I've also tried to run the command with `–rsync-path="sudo rsync"` as suggested in some posts, but still no luck:

```
rsync -avz –rsync-path="sudo rsync" files/* sshwheeluser@ip_address:/home/newproject/public_html/
```

Next I tried to use it with additional `-e "ssh"`:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh" –rsync-path="sudo rsync" files/* sshwheeluser@ip_address:/home/newproject/public_html/
```

which changed the error message (looks like we're getting somewhere):

```
stdin: is not a tty
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
```

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user) suggests that `require_tty` and `tty_tickets` should be disabled in `sudoers`, but I can't find these options in the /etc/sudoers file.

I've added (as recommended) `Defaults !tty_tickets` to the `sudoers`, but still the same message.

Any idea what else I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Selinux logs, `rsync` is probably been blocked by Selinux.

You can also try to run:

```
semanage permissive -a rsync_t
```